# How to do Looping with ResultSet?

Tags: java, loops, resultset

So, I want to loop this ResultSet in order to update the table one by one, but the method while(rsl.next()) can't help me do the looping. It's just work once, and then the others are skipped. Can someone help me fix this problem? Thanks in advance

```
try {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/minimarket";
    String user = "root";
    String pass = "";
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rsl = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM keranjang WHERE pemesan='"+login.userid+"'");

    while (rsl.next()) {
        String nb = rsl.getString("nama_barang");
        String dtl = rsl.getString("detail");
        String beratt = rsl.getString("berat");
        String hrga = rsl.getString("harga");
        String jmlh = rsl.getString("jumlah");
        stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE barang SET stok=stok+'"+jmlh+"' WHERE nama_barang='"+nb+"' AND detail='"+dtl+"' AND berat='"+beratt+"'");
        stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM keranjang WHERE pemesan ='"+login.userid+"' AND nama_barang='"+nb+"'");
    }

    conn.close();
} catch (Exception error) {

}

System.exit(0);
```

Comment: Try `while(rs1.hasNext()){ rs1.next() ...`

Comment: Your code says `if` which isn't a loop.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj `ResultSet` doesn't have a `hasNext()` method.

Comment: `while(rsl.next())` is correct. The problem is probably elsewhere. Please post the actual code where you tried using a `while` loop.

Comment: So tell us, which one is it you are actually using in your code, `if` or `while`?

Comment: ah, sorry. my fault, it actually while, not if. I'm trying to fix it using if since the while doesn't work

Comment: `catch (Exception error)` you will never understand what the error is if you don't at least print the stack trace in there. It may even be a simple typo in one of the queries, for all you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute an `executeUpdate` on your statement an int is returned and most importantly your result set object `rs1` from your query gets closed and can't be accessed anymore since the `Statement` class only handles one query/result set. I haven't tested this myself but I am pretty sure this is the reason.

The solution is to have a separate `Statement` object for the update/delete so that the original `ResultSet` is not affected. Something like below

```
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
Statement updStmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rsl = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM keranjang WHERE pemesan='"+login.userid+"'");

while (rsl.next()) {
    String nb = rsl.getString("nama_barang");
    String dtl = rsl.getString("detail");
    String beratt = rsl.getString("berat");
    String hrga = rsl.getString("harga");
    String jmlh = rsl.getString("jumlah");

    updStmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE barang SET stok=stok+'"+jmlh+"' WHERE nama_barang='"+nb+"' AND detail='"+dtl+"' AND berat='"+beratt+"'");
    updStmt.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM keranjang WHERE pemesan ='"+login.userid+"' AND nama_barang='"+nb+"'");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixes the problem!

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

```
if (rsl.next())
```

fix:

```
while (rsl.next())
```

Debug the app and check if the your connection to the database is valid.

Comment: sorry, I actually use the while, but facing the same problem. The code before is when I'm trying to fix it using if, but not work either

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your problem correctly, there are two possible problems here:

the resultset is null - I assume that this cant be the case as if it was you'd get an exception in your while loop and nothing would be output
the second problem is that resultset.getString(i++) will get columns 1,2,3 and so on from each subsequent row
I think that the second point is probably your problem here.

Let us say you only had 1 row returned, as follows

```
Col 1, Col 2, Col3 
A   , B,    C
```

Your code as it stands would only get A - it wouldn't get the rest of the columns.

I suggest you change your code as follows:

```
ResultSet resultset = ...;
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
while (resultset.next()) {              
        int i = 1;
        while(i <= numberOfColumns) {
            arrayList.add(resultset.getString(i++));
        }
        System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 1"));
        System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 2"));
        System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col 3"));                    
        System.out.println(resultset.getString("Col n"));
}
```

To get the number of columns:

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultset.getMetaData();
int numberOfColumns = metadata.getColumnCount();
```